# Dynamic Formulae from Text in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I want to read in formulae from text and then execute it.

Example 1 -

```
a <- 4
b <- 7 
formula_text2 <- "a * b"
y2 = as.formula(formula_text2)
```

Example 2 - (Using `dplyr`)

```
x <- data.frame("SN" = 1:2, "Age" = c(21,15))
formula_text = "x %>%   mutate( AGE_SQ = Age * Age)"
y = as.formula(formula_text)
```

Both of the above approaches lead to errors.

Answer (score 0):

Use eval/parse:

```
eval(parse(text = formula_text2))
## [1] 28

eval(parse(text = formula_text))
##   SN Age AGE_SQ
## 1  1  21    441
## 2  2  15    225
```